# How can we prove the following inequality?

Tags: calculus, analysis, contest-math

> How can this inequality be proved?
>
> $$
> \max_{i \leq j \leq p} \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{q} a_{ij}^{2}}  \leq \left\Vert  \left( \begin{matrix} a_{11} & \dots & a_{1p} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\a_{q1} & \dots & a_{qp} \end{matrix} \right) \right\Vert \leq \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{q} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{p} a_{ij}^{2} }
> $$

Comment: Another Putnam problem right? What did you try?

Comment: Is that a determinant?